# Backbone - Render collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I'm trying to make an application with Backbonejs and this is the first time I use a Front-end Javascript framework, except for JQuery.

I didn't yet understand how the rendering works.

My Example:

```js
render: function() {


            var events = this.collection.fetch({

                success: function (model, response) {

                    console.log("Response is " + response);

                    var events = model.toJSON();

                    console.log(events.length);
                    console.log(model.toJSON());

                    return model.toJSON();

                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log("Errore during data fetch");
                }
            });


            this.$el.html(this.template({events:this.collection.toJSON()}));

            console.log("Event list: " + events.length);

},
```

The code above is the render callback of my view. 
Inside the success collection fetch I get the data in json format from my API and I successfully log it on the console, but outside the fetch I don't have this data anymore and my view collection seems to be just an empty Backbone object.

Can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong and how rendering works ?

Enrico :)

Comment: jQuery is not a framework... it's a library.. How did you come up with this code..? Do you know that fetch is asynchronous..? `var events = this.collection.fetch` or what fetch  method actually returns..? `success: function (model, response) {` or what will be the first parameter of fetch methods success callback..?  it's all well documented... please read the documentation. `return model.toJSON();` what is the use of returning from success callback...?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what `render` basically does it just inject some html code into the view's `el` (element). 
It could be done by using template engine such as `handlebars` or `mustache` or just using the generic backbone (actually underscore) template, as you did in your code.

What we usually do, is initializing the view the way that it listens to the model it is attached to, or collection in your case.
It is not a very good practice to fetch data within render, as it should only use the already fetched data.

So what you could do, is to initialize your view this way:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize    :   function(){
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "change", this.render);
  },
  redner    :   function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template({events:this.collection.toJSON()}));
  }
});
```

In this code, the view listens to changes occurring on the collection attached to it. When I say changes, I mean changes to any of the models in the collection, including when the collection is fetched for the first time.
So the `listenTo` method will fire the `render` method everytime there's a change in your collection, and by that the whole view will re-render.
This obviously happens when the collection is fetched for the first time.

And for the fetching itself? once youv'e binded the `change` event to the view, you can fetch it anywhere in your app, not necessarily inside the view.